# Transfer form Free trial to Partner Account on Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

As a new dev on Shopify, I create an account on Shopify and it gives me 14 days free trial after a few days passed I know about Shopify partner Program where I have no time limitation. so now I want to know is there any way to transfer my account old account (which have 14 days free trial) under the partner program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no way to convert your existing Shopify store (14 Day Trial Store) into a development store (Partner Account) with an unlimited trial period. You can transfer the content manually to a development store and take more time until you are ready to launch your store.

Also There aren't any specific ways to extend Shopify free trial once you have started the free trial already. Shopify provides very limited promotional offers. You can hardly find any Shopify coupon codes offering big promotions.

You can choose to start a new test Shopify store with a free trial option
Another option could be contacting Shopify customer service team. Once you're near to expiry of your 14-days-trial, contact Shopify’s customer service and request them to extend your trial.